# Setting background color for a text in XSLFO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Im very new to the XSLFO.
I have a requirement to color a text entry based on some condition.
which i do using the snippet

```
<fo:inline color = "red">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</fo:inline>
```

With the above snippet i am able to set the forecolor of the text to RED. My question is how to set the background color for the same.

I can add background color using

```
 <fo:inline color = "red">
   <fo:block background-color = "yellow">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </fo:block> 
 </fo:inline>
```

But this is making my entry come on a separate line which isnt my requirement

Though the xslfo documentation says there is a property available for 
to add the background color for a text.

```
 <fo:inline background-color = "yellow">
 Hello,World
 </fo:inline>
```

Im using the xslfo version 1.0

Anyone out there to help me out ?

Regards

Comment: Are the S-O users on a holiday :)

Comment: Works for me (FO input http://pastebin.com/7sSMNhrd and PNG output http://imgur.com/n8NkD.png using FOP 0.95). What FO processor are you using? Perhaps you could post a complete, minimal example XSL-FO which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi Jukka ... from where can i check the version number of the FOP ?

Comment: @this-Me, you can use the `-v` command line option to get the FOP version number. The command line reference is here: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/running.html#fop-script

Comment: @this-Me, and if you are using FOP programmatically, I think you can get the version number by calling `org.apache.fop.Version.getVersion()`.

Comment: Hi .. Does this cmd work for Windows. I have not installed any Apache/Java utils....

Comment: Background-color is supported for fo:inline. http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_inline.asp It is often helpful to test your XSL-FO against several FO engines, in order to rule out issues with XSL-FO support and bugs in the engine that you are using. Try running against Antennahouse, renderX, Ibex, or any other engine(most offer a trial version) to see if it is a problem with your XSL-FO or your FO engine.

Answer (score 2):

[background-color is supported for fo:inline](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_inline.asp).

It is often helpful to test your XSL-FO against several FO engines, in order to rule out issues with XSL-FO support and bugs in the engine that you are using.

Try running against [Antennahouse](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo.htm), [renderX](http://www.renderx.com/), [Ibex](http://www.xmlpdf.com/), or any other engine(most offer a trial version) to see if it is a problem with your XSL-FO or your FO engine.